# the type arguments for method system linq enumerable as enumerable - Error

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

```
DataTable tblFiltered = dtable.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(row => row.Field<String>("empsalary") > 12000)
          .OrderByDescending(row => row.Field<String>("empsalary"))
          .CopyToDataTable();
```

The above code throws The Type arguments for the method Syste.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable cannot be inferred from the usage.

Comment: What's the type of `dtable`?

Comment: @dcastro It is a datable

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us the type of `dtable`, but assuming it's `DataTable`, I suspect you *intended* to use [`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable) rather than `Enumerable.AsEnumerable`... in which case you're probably just missing either a `using` directive to import the extension method:

```
using System.Data;
```

... or (more likely) a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly which contains the `DataTableExtensions` type.